# How do I configure apt to use a Proxy.pac file?

Tags: 10.10, apt, proxy

So I have a proxy.pac file at work (it doesn't have a username or password) it's just a simple .pac file.

I've gotten it to work with Chrome so I can surf the web, but apt-get and update do not work. How would I go about making this work?

Im on 10.10 btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In system --> preferences --> network proxy, enable Automatic proxy configuration and enter the URL of the PAC.

Then press apply system wide, and that should do the trick.

Comment: Any hints how to do it in shell? I work on a server with no gui.

Comment: Where "system" menu?  there are a link with screenshots?

Comment: Can I do it by terminal?

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt-get update` failed (on a fresh 11.04 VM) after following the instructions in [DemonWareXT](https://askubuntu.com/users/16036/demonwarext)'s answer (System -> Preferences -> Network Proxy).

I followed the instructions I found in [help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#APT_configuration_file_method) (under "APT configuration file method") and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 with Unity, the following can break your Apt config.

> In system --> preferences --> network proxy, enable Automatic proxy configuration >and enter the URL of the PAC.
>
> Then press apply system wide, and that should do the trick.

The issue is that Apt has no concept of a "no_proxy" and so tries to send all traffic out this proxy. There are a couple ways to work around this, one is to create a specific override file for Apt telling it to use/ignore a proxy. Taken from https://superuser.com/questions/323488/ubuntu-system-wide-proxy-auto-configuration-pac-script

```
Acquire {
    Retries "0";
    HTTP {
        Proxy "";
    };
};
```

The other is after clicking Apply in the Network Proxy page, go edit the /etc/apt/apt.conf file as root `sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` and remove any mentions of proxy in this file.

Comment: Where "system" menu?  there are a link with screenshots?

Comment: No news for UNUNTU 18 LTS? I have problems to submit the password, that seems confused with MSCHAPv2 login (PEAP with no certificate).