# Apt-get failed to fetch from Ubuntu server with error code 404

Tags: apt

I just updated from 10.04 to Oneiric and now I can not use my `apt-get` anymore. When I do I got the following error:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Translation-en
```

I can ping any computer and access internet. `sudo apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` does not work (nor clean or autoclean), `dpkg --configure -a` does not help also. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like a network issue, are you behind a proxy? If so, your configuration might be borked.

Have a look at your `etc/apt/apt.conf` file and check the proxy settings there.

(*Added by user in question after discussing issue on comments*)

```
SOLUTION
miguel@miguel-VirtualBox:~$ cat gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
#Wrong!!!
#Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxyconf/proxy.pac";
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://17X.XX.XX.X:8080";
```

It was an issue with the network settings - an invalid proxy was setup causing the problem.

Comment: Indeed was a networking issue. I was misguided by setting a pac from here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37306/how-do-i-configure-apt-to-use-a-proxy-pac-file. It actually do not set a PAC but you have to chose an IP from your PAC file.

Answer (score 0):

That's it! Everywhere says to add your proxy server to /etc/apt/apt.conf, but I added the proxy URL I use system wide (ie for Chrome etc) and no joy. If however you download the .pac file from the proxy URL, you can work out which actual proxy server you are being redirected to (often based on your IP address), use that URL/IP in /etc/apt/apt.conf and it worked for me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous post, I had the same problem as described above on Ubuntu 14.04.  I was not behind a proxy, but still get the error 404, pointing on a bad resource on my local network (a little NAS adapter that I can't control this issue).  Adding/configure a local proxy (Squid3 was choosed) on my computer and configure apt-get to point to solved my network issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was with certain packets from Ubuntu repository missing which was really weird. The problem was firewall options in my router. Option "Filter Cookies" was enabled. I guess most of us are connecting to ubuntu repo servers via http and ftp instead of https and sftp so router can do all kinds of filtering. 
You can always try changing from http to https in /etc/apt/sources.list

Packets with which I had problem is libhttp-cookies-perl